# distance matrix google maps javascript api3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, distance, duration

I play with distance matrix 
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#distance_matrix

to get the duration from one origin to multiple destinations.
I have this code:

```
var duration = new Array();
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
        origins: [origin],
        destinations: destination,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false
    }, 
    function(response, status)
    {
        if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK)
        {
            var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
            var results = response.rows[0].elements;

            for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++)
                duration[j] = results[j].duration.value;
        }
    });
    alert(duration[0]);
```

but i have alert "undefined". when i put the alert command inside the callback function i have the alert i want. why is that??? how can i fix it?

Thank u in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var duration = new Array();
function calculate_distance(){
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
        origins: [origin],
        destinations: destination,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false
    }, 
    function(response, status)
    {
        if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK)
        {
            var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
            var results = response.rows[0].elements;

            for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++)
                duration[j] = results[j].duration.value;
        }
    });
}
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', calculate_distance);
alert(duration[0]);
```

Try anything like that

Comment: To improve the quality of your post please include how/why your post will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Move the alert in to the callback. The function is a callback that is executed asynchronously.

Comment: the distance matrix can calculate 25 distances per time. I have 200 distances that i want to calculate and then sort them in order to output them  into a table. I can't do that asynchronously because i will have a sorted table of 25 distances per time. i hope u understand what i mean.

Comment: I understand, but that still doesn't the fact that the service you're trying to use involves an asynchronous request. You're going to have to perform batch your requests and store the results for processing after the final batch is completed.

Comment: I have opened a similar question to the OP.  How does one get indication after the *final batch is completed*?

Comment: Count how many queries you have made and how many you have gotten back.